# Extra condition (or proof) for $\int{f_{n}}$ converging to a limit, assuming $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise a.e .and $\int{f}<\infty$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show given $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise a.e. and $\int{f}<\infty$, it follows the sequence {$\int{f_{n}}$} has a limit. But I am not sure if extra condition is required. Can anyone give me a counter-example, or a simple proof?

Edit: a counter-example is already found. What if there is an extra condition  $|f_{n}|\le g_{n}$ and $\int{g_{n}}\to \int{g} \le \infty$ ?

Edit2: It is already shown that this can be proven by Fatou's lemma. Thanks everyone who helped me.

Comment: What kind of convergence are you assuming if you write $f_n\rightarrow f$?

Comment: @Thomas Pointwise. I forgot to mention this.

Comment: here I give you a example X=(0,1),$f_{n}=n^{2}\chi_{(0,1/n)}$, the claim in general is wrong

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence

Comment: @yaoxiao What if I put an extra condition: $|f_{n}|\le g_{n}$ and $\int{g_{n}}\to \int{g} \le \infty$

Comment: @Polymorpher this will be true, just consider Fatou theorem, you will get what you want

Comment: @N.I We do not have a single function to bound each $f_{n}$ therefore this theorem does not apply.

Comment: My point is, you need the extra condition. Since someone already gave a counter-example, I gave you one possible extra condition (and also I missed you edit by 6 minutes).

Comment: @yaoxiao I know it is very easy to use Fatou's lemma to show $\int{f_{n}}=\int{f}$. I was trying to avoid that. But it looks like this cannot be avoided. Thanks!

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108313/an-application-of-the-general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After precision have been brought here is a proof. 
We have $g_n-f_n\geq 0$ hence by Fatou lemma 
$$\int \liminf_n (g_n-f_n)\leq \liminf_n\int  (g_n-f_n) $$
so $\int g-\int f\leq \int g+\liminf_n \int (-f_n)$ and $\limsup_n \int f_n\leq \int f$.

Since $g_n+f_n\geq 0$, we apply the previous job to $-f_n$ to get $-\liminf_n \int f_n\leq -\int f$ hence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int f_n=\int f$.

A shorter way suggested by @Sam L. is to apply Fatou lemma to $g+g_n-|f-f_n|$.

Comment: It does not meet the condition $\int{g_{n}}\to\int{g}$

Comment: What is $g$ in this context?

Comment: It is the limit of $g_{n}$. Sorry, I forgot to mention that...

Comment: Pointwise limit?

Comment: Yes, a.e pointwise limit. I worked out a proof using Fatou's lemma to show this limit exists. Thank you for your help! I have edited my question.

Comment: To apply Fatou's lemma you need $f$ non-negative. Is it the case?

Comment: It can be applied on $g-f$

Comment: But it won't prove that $\int f_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Then show $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ equals, from inequalities in both directions.

Comment: I think it would be easier to consider $g+g_n - |f - f_n|\ge 0$ and apply Fatou to this. Then you'd get convergence $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ in one go.

Comment: Indeed, thanks to that we just apply Fatou one time.