# Can $\int|f_n|d\mu \to \int |f|d\mu$ but not $\int|f_n - f|d\mu \to 0$?

Tags: measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convergence a.e. and of norms implies that in Lebesgue space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space)

I am trying to show that if
$$
\int_X |f_n|d\mu \to \int_X|f|d\mu
$$
where $f$ and all the $f_n$ have finite integral and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then
$$
\int_X |f_n-f|d\mu \to 0.
$$

I worked out a proof in the case that $\mu(X) < \infty$, but it relies on Egoroff's theorem which may fail if $\mu(X) = \infty$. I can't find a counterexample in the case $\mu(X) = \infty$ but I suspect that it may not be true. I was thinking of $X=\mathbb{R}$ but maybe there is a good counting measure counterexample on $\mathbb{N}$.

Does anyone know if this is true in the case $\mu(X) = \infty$, and if so, how might I get started in showing it?

Comment: What if $f_n=-1$ and $f=1$? Then your conclusion fails on $[0,1]$ using Lebesgue measure unless I am missing something.

Comment: @unit3000-21 Missing $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that.  Please disregard my comment then.

Comment: Exact dupe of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83208/8271)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $g_n(x):=|f(x)|+|f_n(x)|-|f(x)-f_n(x)|$. It defines an integrable function, and $g_n\to 2|f|$ pointwise. Furthermore, $g_n\geq 0$. By Fatou lemma,
$$\int_X\liminf_{n\to+\infty}g_n(x)d\mu(x)\leq\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\int_Xg_n(x)d\mu(x).$$ 
The LHS is $2\int_X|f(x)|d\mu(x)$, and the RHS is $2\int_X|f(x)|d\mu(x)+\liminf_{n\to +\infty}-\int_X|f-f_n|d\mu$. This gives 
$$0\leq -\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\int_X|f-f_n|d\mu,$$
which is the wanted result.

In particular, this works without the assumption of finiteness of the measure (we just need a positive measure).

Comment: @sos440 Thanks! I didn't know it was called Scheffé lemma.

Comment: I can never come up with these clever applications of Fatou's lemma...