# Extension of Fatou's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral

let $X$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integrable functions, $f_n \rightarrow f\text{ a.e.}$ on $ X$.
I want to show if (1) holds, then (2) holds too.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_X |f_n| \, d\mu=\int_X |f| \, d\mu,\tag{1}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_X |f_n-f| \, d\mu=0.\tag{2}$$

My attempt:

I have proven that (2) holds for nonnegative $f$.
Then for the general case, I split the set to $E^+=\{x: f \geq 0\}$ and $E^-=\{x: f \leq 0\}$:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{E^+} f_n \, d\mu-\int_{E^+} f \, d\mu -\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{E^-} f_n \, d\mu+\int_{E^-} f \, d\mu=0$$

But I don't know how to proceed from here!

Comment: Your sets $E^+$ and $E^-$ depend on $n$. Is it intended?

Comment: @did: sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: You should also assume that $f$ is integrable, otherwise the result won't be true.

Comment: Also, if you already have it for non-negative $f$, for the general case you could consider the sequence $(f_n + |f|)$

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51502 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/222039

Answer (score 1):

As Lukas Geyer points out, the result isn't true unless $f$ is integrable. To see why, consider $f_n(x) = n$. Clearly, $f(x) = \infty$. Also:
$$
\int_X f_n \, d\mu = n \mu(X)
$$

Thus:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n \, d\mu = \int_X f \, d\mu = \infty
$$

Yet:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X |f_n - f| \, d\mu = \infty \neq 0
$$

Now, assuming $f$ is integrable, we have:
$$
\left||f_n - f| - |f_n|\right| \le |f|
$$

Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X \left(|f_n - f| - |f_n|\right) \, d\mu = - \int_X |f| \, d\mu
$$

Rearrange to get the required result.

Comment: You should write 
$$
| |f_n - f| - |f_n| | \le |f|
$$
to use the dominated convergence theorem on $|f_n - f| - |f_n|$(what you wrote needs to be corrected but it's true, no worries).

Comment: You don't seem to assume that the measure space has finite measure. Does that mean you got "the wrong proof" that the exercise assumed the OP to pull off?... I'm wondering.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I wanted to show that the inequality came from the triangle inequality. What I wrote clearly implies what you wrote. I also didn't want to write all steps in detail. :) As for the finiteness of the space, yeah it's not required for the proof. I used it in the counterexample though.