# Show that $\int\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert\,d\lambda\to\int\left\lvert f\right\rvert\,d\lambda\implies\int\left\lvert f_n-f\right\rvert\,d\lambda\to0$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> Let $\,f, f_n $ be Lebesgue integrable functions mapping reals to extended reals such that, almost everywhere, $\,f_n \to f $.
>   Show that $$\int\left\lvert\,f_n\right\rvert\,d\lambda\to\int\left\lvert \,f\right\rvert\,d\lambda\implies\int\left\lvert\,f_n - f\right\rvert\,d\lambda\to0$$

I have shown the converse by breaking absolute values down into the sum of positive and negative parts. I did not use the almost everywhere convergence condition, so I am expecting that to be important here. It makes me think of the DCT, but I cannot figure out how to use that since there is no (to me) obvious bound.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222039